# Upper bound on number of starting positions of a grid coloring game

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory, ramsey-theory

Let's play a game!  The game has the following rules:

Let $G$ be a $N\times N$ grid.  To each grid square $(x,y)\in G$, assign either $true$ or $false$; call this mapping $C$ (that is, if $(x,y)$ is $false$, then $C(x,y)=false$).  Finally, define $\omega = \|\{C(x,y)\in G| C(x,y)=true\}\|$.

Next, we have the following actions:

$$
C(x,y) = C(x+1,y+1) = true \implies C(x+1,y)=C(x,y+1):=true\\
C(x,y) = C(x+2,y) = true \implies C(x+1,y):=true\\
C(x,y) = C(x,y+2) = true \implies C(x,y+1):=true
$$

That is, if two "diagonally adjacent" grid squares are both $true$,  then the "orthogonally adjacent" grid squares turn $true$.  Also, if two grid squares which are $true$ would be adjacent except for a $false$ grid square in between, then the "in between" grid square turns $true$.

The game ends when no further actions are possible.  You win if $\forall(x,y)\in G, C(x,y)=true $.

I'm looking for the smallest $\omega$ required to win the game given $N$.  I know that $\omega \leq N$, as we can define a set of grid squares $\{ (x,x) | x\in\{1,2,\dots,N\}$ that will win the game.  Is this upper bound strictly equal?

Lastly, I'm tagging this as Ramsey theory because I consider $true$ and $false$ to be colorings of the grid squares.  Please remove this tag if it is inappropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimum is $\omega = N$, which is achieved by placing true along the diagonal.

**Hint:** Consider the perimeter of the squares marked true. Apply the [Invariance Princple](https://brilliant.org/discussions/thread/invariance-and-monovariance-principle-2/).

Comment: Noticing that the perimeter of the true squares remained invariant was clever.  Thank you for your insight!